# When to use forEach(_:) instead of for in?

Tags: swift, loops, foreach, sequence, for-in-loop

As documented in both [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach) and [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1689593-foreach) `forEach(_:)` Instance methods:

> Calls the given closure on each element in the **sequence** in the same
>   order as a for-in loop.

Nevertheless, adapted from [Sequence Overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence):

> A sequence is a list of values that you can step through one at a
>   time. *The most common way* to iterate over the elements of a sequence
>   is to use a **for-in loop**.

Implying that iterating sequence by `forEach(_:)` or `for in`:

```
let closedRange = 1...3

for element in closedRange { print(element) } // 1 2 3

closedRange.forEach { print($0) } // 1 2 3
```

Or (Array):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]

for element in array { print(element) } // 1 2 3

array.forEach { print($0) } // 1 2 3
```

Would gives the same output.

Why `forEach(_:)` even exist? i.e what is the benefit of using it instead of the `for in` loop? would they be the same from performance point view?

As an assumption, it could be a syntactic sugar especially when working with *functional programming*.

Comment: From the performance perspective `forEach` is **m u c h** slower than a `for loop`. But it can also be used conveniently as an equivalent to Objective-C's `makeObjectsPerformSelector :`

Comment: @vadian - In debug builds it's much slower. Not necessarily true in release builds (depending upon other things in your code, obviously). For example, I just benchmarked iterations through arrays with millions of objects in release build and the performance difference was indistinguishable.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the feedback. Indeed my "benchmark tests" were performed in debug mode (just ⌘Running the project)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is no performance benefit offered by `forEach`. In fact, [if you look at the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1bae49950e9b4934b6fd4abecf68a10181e60736/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L1058), the `forEach` function actually simply performing `for`-`in`. For release builds, the performance overhead of this function over simply using `for`-`in` yourself is immaterial, though for debug builds, it results in a negligible (but observable) performance impact.

The main advantage of `forEach` is realized when you are doing functional programming, you can add it to a chain of functional calls, without having to save the prior result into a separate variable that you'd need if you used `for`-`in` syntax. So, instead of:

```
let objects = array.map { … }
    .filter { … }

for object in objects {
    …
}
```

You can instead stay within functional programming patterns:

```
array.map { … }
    .filter { … }
    .forEach { … }
```

The result is functional code that is more concise and with less syntactic noise.

FWIW, the documentation for [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach), [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1689593-foreach), and [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2906738-foreach) all remind us of the limitations introduced by `forEach`, namely:

> 1. You cannot use a `break` or `continue` statement to exit the current
>    call of the `body` closure or skip subsequent calls.
> 2. Using the `return` statement in the `body` closure will exit only from
>    the current call to `body`, not from any outer scope, and won't skip
>    subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Is it mean that we should go with `forceah` only with functional programming?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to insist that one must _only_ use it in conjunction with functional programming. It's a nice concise syntax that you can use wherever you want. I was merely suggesting that its greatest utility is when used in conjunction with functional programming, where `for`-`in` pattern really becomes quite cumbersome, in contrast.

Comment: @Rob Per your suggestion, I posted a derivative question related to this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743259/use-foreach-to-nil-out-values-in-an-array

Comment: Great point about chaining. That was not obvious to me and I have a few places in mind to go convert to .forEach just for this reason.

Answer (score 25):

I recently ran across a use case where using `forEach`was preferable in a tangible way to `for in`. Let's say you want to remove all sublayers from a layer. A statement such as the below doesn't work as you need to unwrap the `[CALayer]`

```
for layer in self.videoContainerView.layer.sublayers!
```

If sublayers are nil, you will get a crash. This forces you to check to see if there are sublayers first. However, a `forEach` makes this much simpler as in the following:

```
self.videoContainerView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

Answer (score 20):

They are more or less interchangeable, but there are two important differences.

1. `break`/`continue` only work in a `for .. in`
2. `return` in `forEach` will exit the closure, but will not halt the iteration.

The reason for this is that `for .. in` is a **special form** in the language (which allows break and continue to work as you expect). It is something that you can't implement in an identical way using the language itself.

However, `forEach` is not a special form and can be re-implemented identically by writing it as a function.

```
extension Sequence {
    func myOwnForEach(_ body: (Self.Element) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        let it = Self.makeIterator()
        while let item = it.next() {
            body(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above answers one more reason that differentiates `for` loop from `forEach` is that with `for` loop we can also chose to implement that logic using `where` based pattern matching instead, like

```
for adBanner in adBanners where !adBanner.isLoading {
```

The above kind of control flow related features are what makes for loops so powerful, but if we don’t need that level of control, using a call to forEach might give us slightly simpler-looking code.

So in short using a `for` loop gives us a much greater degree of control over an iteration

Comment: You can do the same thing with foreach by using a filter. `adBanners.filter { $0.isLoading }.forEach { }`