# Split Swift Array by Object Type

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that has two kinds of custom objects in it like this:

```
let array = [TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem()]
```

I want to split it into an array of arrays based on the `SectionItem()` objects that are in it so that each `SectionItem()` is the first item in each array like this (with the first array not having a section item):

```
let newArray = [
  [TaskItem(), TaskItem()],
  [SectionItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem()],
  [SectionItem(), TaskItem()]
]
```

Basically want it to behave like the `components:separatedBy:` method on Swift strings like this:

```
let newArray = array.components(separatedBy: SectionItem) //This isn't real
```

Is this possible in **Swift 4**?

Comment: So in your case you want three arrays of `TaskItem`, right?

Comment: Yeah, I could work with it if it only have `TaskItem` objects.

Comment: I guess you've to write the code for it, there isn't such inbuilt method that can do it

Comment: Just to make sure that I got it right, based on your example array, your expected result is: `[[TaskItem, TaskItem], [TaskItem, TaskItem, TaskItem], [TaskItem]]`, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with dropping the `SectionItem`s in the split you can use:

```
array.split { $0 is SectionItem }
```

If you're not, and you're okay with something a little uglier you can do something like this:

```
let reduce: [[Item]] = array.reduce([]) { (nextPart, item) -> [[Item]] in
    var next = nextPart
    if item is SectionItem {
        next.append([item])
    } else if var items = next.popLast() {
        items.append(item)
        next.append(items)
    } else {
        next.append([item])
    }
    return next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be really straight forward. You just need to iterate over your elements and conditionally cast them from Any to your TaskItem type. If it succeeds append the element to the first subarray otherwise increase the result index and append a new subarray empty to the result:

```
struct TaskItem { }
struct SectionItem { }

let array: [Any] = [TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem()]

var result: [[TaskItem]] = []
result.append([])
var index = 0

for element in array  {
    if let task = element as? TaskItem {
        result[index].append(task)
    } else if !result[index].isEmpty {
        index += 1
        result.append([])
    }
}

print(result) // [[TaskItem, TaskItem], [TaskItem, TaskItem, TaskItem], [TaskItem]]
```

Comment: i think we can directly use for each loop to iterate

Comment: There is always more than one way to accomplish the same result

Comment: Btw your result is of type Any. You should conditionally cast instead of checking if is Type

Comment: Do you think that could we achieve it by using *higher-order functions*? for instance, a combination of filtering and reducing...

Comment: @AhmadF Probably yes. I tried to show him  the steps necessary to accomplish what he wants. Btw it can't get any faster than the code above

Comment: @LeoDabus which part in my code make execution slower than you as you say `Btw it can't get any faster than the code above`  Just for information don't  misunderstand it.

Comment: @Jaydeep Vyas I said it can't get any faster than that, I didn't say yours is slower. forEach and for in loops are equivalent :)

Comment: @LeoDabus "forEach and for in loops are equivalent", I am not so sure about it, I already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333177/when-to-use-foreach-instead-of-for-in) :)

Comment: @AhmadF As you can see in your question for the code above there is no difference at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let array: [Any] = [TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem(), SectionItem(), TaskItem()]

var indexes:[Int] = []
for i in 0..<array.count {
    let item = array[i]
    if item is SectionItem {
        indexes.append(i)
    }
}

var result:[[Any]] = []
for i in 0...indexes.count {
    if (i != indexes.count) {
        let index = indexes[i]
        let sindex = i == 0 ? 0 : indexes[i-1]
        result.append(Array(array[sindex..<index]))
    } else {
        let sindex = i == 0 ? 0 : indexes[i-1]
        result.append(Array(array[sindex..<array.count]))
    }
}

//result [[TaskItem(), TaskItem()], [SectionItem(), TaskItem(), TaskItem()], [SectionItem(), TaskItem()]]
```