# Pass array of objects into another class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I've created an `achievementArray` of my `AchievementObject` class and appended all the necessary values. For testing purposes I've hard-coded the first index. I want to pass this array into my `AchievementDatabase` class so I can check the size of the array. (I want to get the client-side working before integrating my actual database).

I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type `AppDelegate.AchievementObject.Type` to expected argument type `AppDelegate.AchievementObject`

This is my relevant code, all in the `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
var achievementArray = [AchievementObject]();
achievementArray.append(AchievementObject(achievementID: -1, achievementName: "achievementName", achievementDescription: "achievementDescription")); //Append to allow subscripting

achievementArray[1].achievementID = 1;
achievementArray[1].achievementName = "Hello World!";
achievementArray[1].achievementName = "Be Born!";

debugPrint(achievementArray[1].achievementName); //Returns Hello World!

var achievementDB = AchievementDatabase(achievementArray: AchievementObject); *<-- Error Here*

class AchievementObject {

    var achievementID: Int;
    var achievementName: String;
    var achievementDescription: String;
    init(achievementID: Int, achievementName: String, achievementDescription: String) {
        self.achievementID = achievementID;
        self.achievementName = achievementName;
        self.achievementDescription = achievementDescription;
        return;
    }

class AchievementDatabase {
    //Act as a local database storage until connection is made
    var numAchievements: Int = 1; //Will change to achievementArray.count();
    init(achievementArray: AchievementObject) {

        for i in 1...numAchievements {
            debugPrint("i: \(i)");
            //var achievement = AchievementObject(id:i); //
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some changes to do in your code. Anyway
the main problem is that `AchievementDatabase` is getting an `AchievementObject`, but actually you need an array, then you should use the notation `[AchievementObject]`.

So you may want to follow this refactoring:

**Test:**

```
var achievementArray = [AchievementObject]()
achievementArray.append(AchievementObject(achievementID: -1, achievementName: "achievementName", achievementDescription: "achievementDescription"))
achievementArray[0].achievementID = 1
achievementArray[0].achievementName = "Hello World!"
achievementArray[0].achievementName = "Be Born!"

let achievementDB = AchievementDatabase(achievementArray: achievementArray)
print(achievementDB.achievementArray.count)
```

**Model:**

```
class AchievementObject {
    var achievementID: Int
    var achievementName: String
    var achievementDescription: String

    init(achievementID: Int, achievementName: String, achievementDescription: String) {
        self.achievementID = achievementID
        self.achievementName = achievementName
        self.achievementDescription = achievementDescription
    }
}

class AchievementDatabase {
    var achievementArray: [AchievementObject]

    init(achievementArray: [AchievementObject]) {
        self.achievementArray = achievementArray
        achievementArray.enumerated().forEach { (index, value) in
            print("index: \(index), value: \(value.achievementName)")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Observations**:

1. since is redundant, please avoid to use semicolon `;`
2. `AchievementDatabase` was getting an object, but you should pass an array like `[AchievementObject]`
3. you may want to use a compact [forEach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach), instead of a verbose `for i..n`, nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334483/2450755).
4. you was accessing to position 1 of the array, which is actually the second position of an array with just 1 element, hence -> crash
5. the best way to access crash-free to such position is using `achievementArray.first`
6. `AchievementObject` should be a struct, not a class. Then you don't even need to provide the init.
7. If the values of a given `AchievementObject` won't change once set, change all of the properties to let from var.

Comment: Other suggestions. 1. `AchievementObject` should be a struct, not a class. Then you don't even need to provide the `init`. 2. If the values of a given `AchievementObject` won't change once set, change all of the properties to `let` from `var`. 3. `numAchievements` isn't need in `AchievementDatabase` any more.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 var achievementDB =  = AchievementDatabase(achievementArray: achievementArray))
```

Comment: Throws an invoke error when I declare achievementDB and undeclared type errors in the class.

Comment: This answer is half correct. You also need to change `init(achievementArray: AchievementObject) {` to `init(achievementArray: [AchievementObject]) {`. Now it expects an array.